# a bluetooth headphones that allow to configure low battery warning sound

Tags: smartphones, bluetooth, headphones

Is there bluetooth headphones that allow to configure low battery warning sound?

for some reason hardware developers make these sounds too loud, or high pitch, or too repetitive (instead of beep once, it keeps beeping for 10mins saying battery is low, what makes absolutely no sense...), i got so annoyed that i almost smashed my headphone into dust (i did it in my imagination tho, many times..).

So now i will only buy another bluetooth headphone if i can configure these warning sounds volume at least. I guess it must have a configuration app that can send commands to the connected bluetooth headphone.

does any like that exist?

Obs.: another alternative would be to create a necklace with a smartphone battery and connect the bluetooths on it instead of their tiny batteries, as i already have to link both with a wire to prevent them falling from my ears.. so the beeps would not happen in less than a few days, what would be perfet, but i am not sure it can be done because of the battery voltage, any tip?

ps.: i have to use bluetooth headphones because my p2 jack wired headphones conection on my smartphone is damaged, so using it is not an option (i damaged it because i kept reconnecting many times to avoid the loud bang bang sound netflix makes before every episode, that hurt my ears)